# Choosing significance level if data less normal

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, error, normality-assumption

If my data is not a very good approximation of normality, but I continue to run a t-test, will choosing a lower significance level offset some of the error caused by the fact that the data is not perfectly normal? Or is this unethical/won't reduce error.

Comment: The t-test is quite robust to many deviations from normality.

Answer (score -1):

What is the size of your sample and how 'non-normal' is your data? If its more than around 30 observations (for highly non normal data you may need more than 30) , normality assumptions are not needed (going by [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem))

If you have lesser observations (at least 8+), go with bootstrap resampling to get a better estimate of standard error and then recalculate the p values from it